# How might I download the Explorer plugin on 64 bit Notepad++?

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I'm looking to install the Explorer plugin on 64 bit Notepad++, I'm unsure how to do this as the plugin manager is missing, which I've been lead to believe is an issue with the 64 bit version as a whole and not just a bug with the one I have on my PC. I've tried to see what downloading the 32 bit Notepad++ would do and it seems to load /run okay but it is unable to download plugins. Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/funap/npp-explorer-plugin

There are no available Explorer plugins now to support Notepad++ 64-bit, but you can try following steps as same or try notpad++ 32-bit.
**view->folder as workspace->right click folder as workspace panel->add your project path**

if anyone finds another plugin can replace old Explorer plugin as the same function, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is now a 64bit version on GitHub: https://github.com/funap/npp-explorer-plugin

Comment: Why the downvote without any feedback? I have this plugin installed and working perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

There is one perfectly good explorer here, that I use.
All you need to do is to copy it to plugin folder inside installation folder od Notepad ++
https://github.com/krskrs/npp-explorer/downloads

Comment: This one is for the 32bit version